# Finding first datetime by group

Tags: r, plyr

Hello I am looking for an equivalent with `plyr` (or any other package but data.table cause of [bug #2531](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2531&group_id=240&atid=975)) of "min datetime by group"

```
set.seed(1)
datetimes=c(rep(as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 08:00:00"),3) , rep(as.POSIXct("2011-01-03 08:00:00"),3)) + rnorm(6)
groups=c(rep('a',3),rep('b',3))
X = data.frame(datetime=datetimes,group=groups)
X
#                  datetime group
#2011-01-01 07:59:59.373546     a
#2011-01-01 08:00:00.183643     a
#2011-01-01 07:59:59.164371     a
#2011-01-03 08:00:01.595280     b
#2011-01-03 08:00:00.329507     b
#2011-01-03 07:59:59.179531     b
```

expected answer

```
                    datetime group
2011-01-01 07:59:59.164371     a
2011-01-03 07:59:59.179531     b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ddply`.

```
ddply(X, .(group), summarise, first_datetime = min(datetime))
```

More concise, but not quite as clear is this variant:

```
ddply(X, .(group), colwise(min))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
aggregate(datetime ~ group, X, min)
```